# The resource Quad.fbx could not be loaded from the resource file

Tags: unity-game-engine, resources

I'm working on a live Unity project that is several years old. At some point, someone erased the Quad.fbx primitive from the asset manager (!!!). I "restored it" by creating a new Quad fbx file in Blender, and that worked for a long time, but with 4.5.4p1 it has broken again.

How do I restore the "internal" primitives that aren't exposed in the assets folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be a lot easier for your to make a backup of your actual installation and then wipe out everything and perform a clean install. Otherwise I'm afraid you'll constantly keep falling victim of update changes that rely on previous installs.